# При активном placeholder менять заливку у SVG и нижнего border'a

Tags: html, css, svg, input, placeholder

Имеется `placeholder`.
Я хочу сделать так,- чтобы когда он был активен, то есть человек начинал писать что-то или просто кликнул по нему, то менялся цвет  у `SVG`-элемента, и у нижнего `border`'a.
 Желательно чтобы нижний `border` заливался цветом по мере того как человек пишет слово.

```css
.cost__button-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cost__button-wrapper">
  <svg class="icon__svg-small icon__cost">
    <use xlink:href="img/icons/sprite.svg#avatar"/>
  </svg>
  <input class="cost__placeholder" id="region" type="text" placeholder="Даниил">
</div>
```

Comment: Активный `placeholder`???  Это что-то  новое)))

Comment: Ну вы же прекрасно понял о чем я, лучше бы посоветовали как сделать, а не шутили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let cost = document.querySelector('.cost__placeholder');

let icon__svg = document.querySelector('.icon__svg-small');

cost.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  icon__svg.style.background = 'green';
  icon__svg.style.borderBottom = '5px solid red';
})
cost.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  icon__svg.style.background = 'red';
  icon__svg.style.borderBottom = '5px solid green';
})
```

```css
.cost__button-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}

.cost__placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 111111;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cost__button-wrapper">
  <svg class="icon__svg-small icon__cost">
    <use xlink:href="img/icons/sprite.svg#avatar"/>
  </svg>
  <input class="cost__placeholder" id="region" type="text" placeholder="Даниил">
</div>
```